# Remote Login Issue with iPhone

Tags: iphone, authentication, connection, asihttprequest

I'm building a free App, that needs to present some data only to logged users. I'll try to explain myself better. Assuming the user is already registered into the database, the first time he choose the private area, a view asks him the username and password.

My problem is: how should I send them to the server and see if it accepts the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use the [**ASIHTTPRequest**](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) library and its ASIFormDataRequest class for easily POSTing data to a webserver and acting on the response.

Comment: Not very well documented but it does the job greatly. Thank you.